# How to fix row width of the read xlsm file in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

How can we fix the width of the each row.
Here is an example code and sample data file ([sample data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data))to reproduce error:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Use readxl"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                    accept = c(".xlsx")
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$contents <- renderTable({

        req(input$file1)

        inFile <- input$file1

        readxl::read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
      })
    }
  )
)
```

As we observe, the 1st and 2nd row width are not same. Is there a possibility may be using "DT" to fix row width ?
[Row width of read xlsm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/298y8.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you type `?renderTable` in R console (or look it up on [shiny website](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderTable.html))  you'll see a help page. Amongst other things that can come handy for you, it has a spacing variable which you can use when calling `renderTable()`. Try setting it to large, e.g.

```
output$contents <- renderTable({
  iris 
}, spacing = 'l')
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried as follows:
```
server = function(input, output){
      output$contents <- renderTable({
        
        req(input$file1)
        
        inFile <- input$file1
        
        readxl::read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
      },spacing = 'l')
    }
  )
)
```

But still row width is not equal and it always depends on cells read from xlsm.